# How to integrate aws S3 to my android app?

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3

I am trying to figure out what is the best practice to integrate AWS S3 in my android app.

As a pre-work I have an s3 bucket which I can upload\download\delete using the python/java SDK and now I want to implement it in my android app. 
I found on the web different approaches and can not get my head straight what is the recently\correct way doing it.
My research brought the following result:

1. mobile hub - https://grokonez.com/android/uploaddownload-files-images-amazon-s3-android
   or in the amazon offical - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/mobile-hub-add-aws-mobile-user-data-storage.html
2. user pool\cognito -https://101apps.co.za/index.php/item/195-android-and-amazon-s3-secure-file-storage-in-the-cloud
3. github project - https://github.com/nimran/Amazon-S3-Integration-in-Android - when i clone and try to activate it most of the aws calls are deprect.
4. another amazon official, this time using Android SDK - https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/storage

**I am looking for a guide\repo which is up to date and explain the correct way to integrate S3 in an android app.** 
thx

Answer (score 2):

@helpper The best way is to follow the official documentation which contains nice sample code to start, always updatated and easy to follow instead of any other sites.

For now you can follow the [Android Sdk docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/android/start) or the [Amplify framework](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start) but the amplify framework is currently is in Preview stage which will be ready in few days.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Cognito Identity Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html) here to generate temporary AWS Credentials (which are obtained via AWS STS). Those credentials can be further used to invoke relevant AWS S3 API calls, and thus satisfy your application development requirements.

Cognito Identity Pools support both Unauthenticated Access and Authenticated Access, so with relevant roles, you would need to select appropriate IAM JSONs for both cases, to ensure your software remains robust and secure.

Since you are developing your application on Android(with Java), I would highly recommend this official AWS [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) as your starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Check the sample app: [aws labs](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample).
Build the app and customize it accordingly. Just change the settings in "aws configuration file".

Prerequisite:

- Android Studio
- S3 bucket
- aws cognito (identity pool)
- aws IAM role (identity pool role, having access to S3 bucket)

Hope this helps!